# Split points awarded on LOL

Tags: league-of-legends

I currently want to get my second armor upgrade for my account on League, I was wondering how many games I need to win on ranked to get around 150 split points, or how many split points do I get awarded per win on ranked games?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing here: https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/Rank_(League_of_Legends)

- +20 SP when playing primary and secondary role
- +25 SP when drafting Fill
- +30 SP when autofilled

So if you like to play fill, about 6 games. If you don't, 8.

EDIT: Got screwed by this. Its not playing games. Its winning games. So you have to WIN 6 games or 8 if you dont play fill.